# queue not return rear value properly?

Tags: c, queue

i want to create queue with dynamic array, the problem is when i test the q.rear value in int main() (for inserting data later) it's not -1 anymore. Which part did i do wrong?

here's a piece of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int *data;
    int front,rear,max;
    }tqueue;
tqueue create(int size)
{
   tqueue q;
   q.data=(int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));          
   q.front=0;
   q.rear=-1;
   q.max=size;
   return q;   
}
int main()
{
   tqueue q;
   int size=4;
   create(size);
   printf("\n%d",q.rear);
   getch();   
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't assign the result of `create()` to `q`. The following calls `create()` *and discards the result*, leaving `q` in its original state:

```
create(size);
```

To fix, replace the above line with:

```
q = create(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different `tqueue`s, both called `q`. One (the one you create in `create`) you initialize and one (the one you create in `main`) you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign the return value:

```
q = create(size);
```